# What do display custom icon for google map Marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
  var mapOptions = {
  center: currentPosition,
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions)

var home_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: currentPosition,
  map: map,
  icon: "../images/02_button_add.png"
});
```

Above is my code for google map API and trying to display a custom icon on map.
However, when I delete the icon file from folder. The map still show my icon.

Anyone knows what happen?

Comment: What is your question?  [Your code as posted works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/60f162ze/).  What does deleting the icon have to do with anything?  Was the marker your custom marker?  Did you clear your browser cache and reload the map after deleting the marker from the folder?

Comment: I only refresh the browser.

Comment: Are you sure that `"../images/02_button_add.png"` is the right path?

Comment: This is right path. The problem is the map show my icon first time. Then I delete the icon from folder but still show icon after refresh browser.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the browser with `CTRL+F5`? It seems It's loading your old icon from cache

Comment: I tried clear cache. and command + R (mac) to refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display another icon from same folder, you just change file name and hard reload your browser.
If you wish to display default google marker then remove icon property of marker from your code and hard reload your browser

Comment: i refresh the page but not working. What you mean hard reload browser?

Comment: use ctrl+f5 or right click and select option empty cache and hard reload